# Unable to open Ubuntu software app in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-center

Whenever I open Ubuntu Software app, it keeps showing a loading symbol on the top of the screen and closes automatically. I am unable to open the Ubuntu software app because it closes automatically. Please help me out to fix this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a fresh install,be sure to refresh updates,possibly more than once,to get everything up to date and working correctly.Wouldn't hurt to restart the computer,even if not prompted to do so.